# try exception fails inside of a for()

Tags: php

Trying to build a `for` loop with an `exception`:

```
for( $i = 1; $i <= $contxf; $i++) {
  try{
    if($i = $icheck) {
      throw new Exception('Current Page');
  }
  echo '<a href="?pag='.$i.'">'. $i .'</a>&nbsp';
  } catch (Exception $cp) {
    echo $i;
    $i = $i + 1;
  }
```

The code fails to add +1 to $i within the loop.

Comment: if($i == $icheck) this is comparison. what you have done is assignment.

Comment: plus your for is not closed.. add `}` at the end of this code

Comment: May be you need it. But you are incrementing value of $i in catch also.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was if($i = $icheck) instead of if($i == $icheck)
thanks!